# Syntax error, unexpected ''SELECT * FROM members WHERE e' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, syntax

My error:

> syntax error, unexpected ''SELECT * FROM members WHERE e'
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\New folder
>   (2)\loginexec.php on line 63

I already tried:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$login' AND password='$password'";
```

but still having error. How can I fix this?

```html
 
 $login = clean($_POST['user']);
 $password = clean($_POST['password']);
 
 //Create query
 mysql_query 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE email="$login" AND password="$password"';
 $(result=mysql_query($qry);
 //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
//  {
//  $level=$row['position'];
//  }
 //Check whether the query was successful or not
 if($result) {
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   //Login Successful
   session_regenerate_id();
   $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
   $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $confirmation;
   
   session_write_close();
   //if ($level="admin"){
   header("location: order.php");
   exit();
   //}
   //else{
   //header("location: front.php");
   //exit();
   //}
  }else {
   //Login failed
   $errmsg_arr[] = 'Invalid Email add or password';
   $errflag = true;
   if($errflag) {
  $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
  session_write_close();
  header("location: loginindex.php");
  exit();
 }
  }
 }else {
  die("Query failed");
 }
```

Comment: `mysql_query 'SELECT * FROM...` Isn't this just too obvious?!

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecreted use `mysqli`

Comment: Can we see what `clean()` does? I am concerned that you have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code. Also, don't store passwords as plaintext - another security issue. Hash them instead.

Answer (score 1):

You did not assign the query to a variable, you gave

```
mysql_query 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE email="$login" AND password="$password"';
```

assign the query to a variable and then try it..

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=\"$login\" AND password=\"$password\"";
```

once try this...
and i recommend you to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), instead of `mysql`, coz `mysql` is deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email= '".$login."' AND password='".$password."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is a function, so you need to enclose between parenthesis the arguments:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$login' AND password='$password'"
);
```

And remember: double quotes (") does resolve variables like $login and $password (did you use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) with them? clear function is not clear, take caution) but simple quotes (') doesn't.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well I would not use my passwords like that but it seems you need to make mysql_query with 2 parameters is mysql_query(database connection, query)

And I should say start learning mysqli instead of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=$login AND password=$password";
```